# Include only required lodash functions in bundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, lodash

I am working on a Ionic 3 app which uses webpack to create bundle. One of the packages I use (Swing.js) has a `lodash` dependency. When I look into the source code , it uses only 3 `lodash` functions.

But the whole lodash library is loaded in the Ionic bundle. Is there anyway to include only required lodash functions without forking Swing.js ?

Comment: Not likely unless lodash itself has a custom build tool.

Comment: Can there be a webpack plugin which would stop lodash import and go through the code base to find lodash functions and import just them ?

Comment: You could write your own replacements for those methods and sort out how to override the dependency and change it to your own methods source

Comment: Honestly probably easier to fork the swing.js code to modify the dependency.  Webpack and uglifyjs can be use to do more general "tree shaking" to eliminate anything that is definitely not used but ultimately better if you can prune things yourself as well https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: Also after minification and gzip the payload size you save by eliminating relatively small chunks of code isn't going to be that big of a deal, optimize a single image further and you'll likely save as much payload as cleaning up these dependencies will.  Make sure to use the chrome tools to profile and get a timeline to see if the effort is worth it or not.